# Error in appcompat_v7 and every eclipse project

Tags: java, android, eclipse, adt, android-appcompat

I just started android programming and downloaded the latest versions of ADT and android SDK. However, any new project I try to create is having 4 errors.

One of the  errors is " Error executing aapt. Please check aapt is present at /home/nikhil/Android/adt-bundle-linux-x86_64-20140702/sdk/build-tools/android-4.4W/aapt " .
The type of the error is Android Packaging Problem and the problem occurs in appcompat_v7.
The aapt file is exactly at the specified place but somehow eclipse cant execute it.

The other 3 errors are "R cannot be resolved to a variable" and it occurs in MainActivity.java.

I am running Arch Linux 64 bit and using Eclipse IDE for Android Developers 23.0.2.1259578.

I am trying to create My First App and is puzzled to see errors before i wrote a single line of code!

Comment: if you fix appcompat problem , other problem will be solved, what is the error on appcompat? did you clean projects?

Comment: Thanks! Problem solved...the error in appcompat was due to some lack of 32 bit support libraries...

Comment: @tech-nik , Can u plz tell how did u solve this problem. I am stuck on this for long. I am using Ubuntu.

Comment: @Joyson, open a terminal and enter this :- sudo apt-get install ia32-libs

Answer (score 0):

This happends occasionaly and the usual way I fix this is to go into Projects -> Properties -> Android -> then choose appcompat from the list, apply, then go. The R cannot be resolved to a variable is usually because there is an error in one of your XML files which you have to resolve.